# Radix Sort on an array of strings output wrong by 2 words?

Tags: java, arraylist, radix-sort

In this program the task is to rearrange the given strings in word array to be sorted on length and then alphabetically using a radix sort methodology. For example, given the input of:

"bar", "cat", "apple", "bug", "cog", "caper", "antler", "ankle", "bear"

the correct output should be: bar bug cat cog bear ankle apple caper antler

So far, what I have given my current code is: bar bug cat cog bear ankle antler caper apple

Where exactly in my radix sort algorithm did I go wrong? Why is "antler", the string with the greatest length not at the end of the output?

Here is my current code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RadixSort 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String[] words = {"bar", "cat", "apple", "bug", "cog", "caper", "antler", "ankle", "bear"};

        System.out.print("Before Radix Sort: ");
        for (String h : words)
            System.out.print(h + " ");

        strRadixSort(words);

        System.out.print("\n\nAfter Radix Sort: ");
        for (String h : words)
            System.out.print(h + " ");

        System.out.print("\n\nWhat the output should look like: ");
        System.out.print("bar bug cat cog bear ankle apple caper antler");

    }

    public static void strRadixSort(String[] words) 
    {
      ArrayList<String>[] Letterbuckets = new ArrayList[26];

      for (int i = 0; i < Letterbuckets.length; i++) 
      {
          Letterbuckets[i] = new ArrayList<String>();
      }

      boolean exit = false;
      int index = 1;
      int x = 0;

      while (exit == false) 
      {  
        exit = true;

        for (String i : words) 
        {
          int curIndex= i.length() - index; //start at the last char in string i

          if(curIndex < 0)
          {
              break; //We are done evaluating this word, go to the next word
          }

          x = determineLetterBucket(i, curIndex);

          Letterbuckets[x].add(i);
          x = 0;

          if (exit == true && curIndex > 0) 
          {
              exit = false;
          }
        }

        //Rearranges the order of the words in the
        //word array and clears all letter buckets
        //to prepare for the next pass.
        int a = 0;

        for(int k = 0; k < 26; k++) 
        {
          for (String i : Letterbuckets[k]) 
          {
            words[a++] = i;
          }

          Letterbuckets[k].clear();
        }

        //Moves to the next least significant letter
        index += 1;
      }
    }

    //Determines which number bucket the letter should go into
    //e.g. In the string "abc" the char at index 2 is "c",
    //therefore this would mean this word would go into bucket 2
    //which can also be represented as the "c" bucket.
    public static int determineLetterBucket(String currentWord, int currentIndex)
    {
        int bucket = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for(int k = 97; k < 123; k++)
        {
            if(currentWord.charAt(currentIndex) == k)
                bucket = j;
            else
                j++;
        }

        return bucket;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how your "correct output" has anything to do with "alphabetical ascending order". Pretty sure a comes before b and c and should in ascending order therefor come first.

Comment: Agree with upper comment, your order seems random to me, again (I think, someone posted similar question a while ago)

Comment: Seems to be sorted on length and then alphabetically

Comment: What I meant is that the way the "Correct output" has the words arranged is in a matter where words of the same length are in alphabetical order.

Comment: This works: `Arrays.sort(words, Comparator.comparing(String::length).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));`